# Photo Competition 2021-08-09: Food

Tags: photo-competition

### Theme: Food

Candidates can be:

- A mouth watering cooked dish.
- Raw vegetables.
- Raw fruits.
- Desserts.
- Beverages like tea, juices etc.

This theme was suggested by [Aquarius_Girl](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/5205/aquarius-girl).

#### Voting Rules

- View the submissions [sorted by active](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/125744/photo-competition-2021-08-09-food?answertab=active#tab-top) to give every submitter a fair chance
- Vote up as many images as you like
- Please, **up votes only!** Do NOT vote down your competitors! If you don't like an image, don't vote
- **Voting closes on August 23, 2021 at 12:01 AM UTC** (00:01 UTC if you prefer a 24-hour time). The winner will be chosen based on votes at that time.

#### Submission Rules

1. One photo submission per answer. Up to three (3) entries allowed.
2. Post only photos taken by yourself or the person with you.
3. **All entries should include:**

   - a **title** for the photo
   - a **location and date**, if known
   - **camera, lens, and exposure settings**, if known
   - any other explanatory notes, comments, etc., that you want to include (completely optional)
4. The submitted image must conform to this site's content license, Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 ([CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)) with [attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).
5. Do not use this as a forum for photo critique. Use [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=photo.stackexchange.com) instead, or [ask a new question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about your image.

---

#### Next Contest

Suggest a theme by writing a new answer at the [Photo of the Week Theme Ideas](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1740/) thread. Please make sure to check the [PotW theme ideas Archive](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1741/) first, to make sure you aren't recycling a theme.

The highest-voted theme will be the next theme.

Good luck!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image: A productive afternoon guaranteed]

A productive afternoon guaranteed, home

EOS M2, 22mm, f/2.0, 1/60, ISO100

Answer (score 6):

### Onion Volcano

[image]

An onion volcano at my favorite Japanese Steakhouse that got a little out of control.

Pentax K1000 (I think, Nikon F2 also possible given the time frame Mid-Late 2000's), Unknown lens and settings, Kodachrome ISO100, digitized with a Nikon D700 using a PB-4 bellows and a PS-4 slide copy adapter.

Answer (score 5):

**Ruby platter**

A party platter bought for a 40th wedding anniversary

OMD E-10 MK III, 25mm Lumix prime lens
f/1.7, 25mm, 1/640, ISO400, EV -0.3

[image: platter]

Answer (score 5):

### Low & Slow

[image]

Early morning light diffused by clouds and trees illuminates pork butt and 'country style boneless ribs' cut from pork loin that has been smoked with hickory and oak overnight.

Canon EOS 5D Mark II + EF 24-105mmf/4L IS @47mm. ISO 400, f/4, 1/50.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Venice 2014]
**Venice, Italy**
October 2014
Olympus E-M1, 12-40 f2.8 at 12mm, f/5.6, 1/100s

Answer (score 3):

[image]

A cake made by  my 8 year old niece on her mom's wedding anniversary.

Nikon D5600, 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6
1/13 sec at f/5.6 , 55 mm, ISO 100

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Fruit pancake at one of the highest rated breakfast restaurants in Chiang Mai. While it looks delicious, I remember the taste being quite disappointing. Oh well, at least the presentation is nice. ;)

Taken in December of 2018 with a Samsung Galaxy S9 at f/2.4, 1/100 shutter time at 4.3mm with ISO 50.

Answer (score 3):

[image]
**Thematic Pancakes**
On an Alaska salmon fishing trip in Aug 2019, one of the guys made pancakes to celebrate our good fishing fortunes and friendship. The features were drawn with pancake batter using a squirty bottle, The fill was done a few minutes later (features cooks longer than the fill giving the contrast). For one of the guys he made a figurine that is inappropriate to show on this forum.

Sony RX100, f/4, 1/500s, 17.8mm (48mm FF equivalence), ISO 400

Comment: something tells me the inappropriate figurine is the more interesting photo. =)

Answer (score 3):

### Ripening

Los Gatos, CA

May 29th 2021

Nikon D500 with Sigma 150-600

ISO 360, f/7.1, 1/2000

[image]

Answer (score 3):

### Supposedly, this is food.

Except, how do I eat it?

[image: Coconut]

Canon 5D Mk.III, EF100mm f/2.8 Macro USM

ISO 400, f/18, 0.4 s

Answer (score 2):

**Black Candy**

[image]

May 20, 2020, New York City
iPhone XS Max, 4.25mm, f/1.8, 1/83 second

Some horehound drops I dumped onto a white plate in an attempt to try black and white photography.  This is before I digitally converted to black and white...

Comment: I was _this close_ to wanting to downvote because my first reaction was "those aren't food! They're river rocks!!" But then I realized they were food, and I wanted several upvotes to counter my initial reaction. =)

Comment: @scottbb Don't worry...  If my father saw me eating those close he'd probably tell me to "eat some real food."  Especially if I was taking them from him!

Comment: @scottbb Surely you've been told on at least a few occasions, "Go eat rocks!"

Comment: @MichaelC lol. Both in jest, and also mostly certainly not in jest. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

### In the Garden

Los Gatos, CA

May 28th 2021

Nikon D500 with Sigma 150-600

ISO 2851, f/6.3, 1/250

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Title: Whirly Pop
Taken May 20, 2012 in Charleston, SC at a local market. Taken with a Canon PowerShot, f/5, 1/20 sec., ISO-200. Converted to B&W using a photoshop charcoal filter.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Tuppence a bag**

This guy sits in St James Park, London with his wife and they feed the birds (mostly pigeons!). I took the snap as I was walking, so as to not catch his gaze. Taken 10th August 2021.

[image]

[image: Bird man]

Answer (score 1):

**Waiter, there's a plane in my coffee!**

1940's themed cafe in Stratford-Upon-Avon, with coffee art provided. 9th August 2021.

[image]

[image: Waiter, there's a plane in my coffee!]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*Cheese plate*

- **Location/Date:** Slovenia, 17.07.2021
- **Camera:** Canon R5
- **Lens:** EF 50mm F1.8
- **Settings:** F4 | 1/500 | ISO 800